# Form submit stay on same page, post using curl

Tags: php, curl

I have a form (form.php) and a page that processes the form (record.php). I wish for the user to stay on form.php when the form is submitted, so I have been using curl. Currently when I load the page, it just buffers for hours and doesn't do anything, and I don't know why. This is what I have as my form.php

```
<?php
       function post_to_url($url, $data) {
       $fields = '';
       foreach($data as $key => $value) { 
          $fields .= $key . '=' . $value . '&'; }
       rtrim($fields, '&');        
       $post = curl_init();        
       curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
       curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
       curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
       $result = curl_exec($post);
       curl_close($post);
       }
       if(isset($_POST["ename"])){
       $ename = $_POST["ename"];
       $message = $_POST["message"];
       $etype = $_POST["etype"];
       $date = $_POST["datepicker"];
       $question = $_POST["question"];
       $rtype = $_POST["rtype"];
       $allowed1 = strtolower($_POST["allowed1"]);
       $allowed2 = strtolower($_POST["allowed2"]);
       $allowed3 = strtolower($_POST["allowed3"]);
       $allowed4 = strtolower($_POST["allowed4"]);
       $eforward = strtolower($_POST["eforward"]);
       $data = array(
       "ename" => "$ename",
       "message" => "$message",
       "etype" => "$etype",
       "date" => "$$date",
       "question" => "$question",
       "rtype" => "$rtype",
       "allowed1" => "$allowed1",
       "allowed2" => "$allowed2",
       "allowed3" => "$allowed3",
       "allowed4" => "$allowed4",
       "eforward" => "$`enter code here`eforward"
        );

    post_to_url("URL to Post to", $data);

    }

    ?>

    <form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="form.php">
      <label for="ename">Event Name</label>
      <input name="ename" type="text" id="ename">
      <label for="message">Message</label>
      <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
      <label for="etype">Response Required</label>
      <select name="etype" size="2" id="etype">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">No</option>
        <option value="1">Yes</option>
      </select>
     Event Resender End Date: 
      <input name="datepicker" type="text" id="datepicker" size="10">
    MM/DD/YYYY <select name="eforward" id="eforward">
                    //dynamic select            </select><br>
      <label for="question">Question for responses</label>
    <input type="text" name="question" id="question" maxlength="18"><br>
      <label for="rtype">Response Type</label>
      <select name="rtype" size="3" id="rtype">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">Standard Yes/No Response</option>
        <option value="1">Create Responses</option>
        <option value="2">Get Users Own Response</option>
      </select>
Response Options<br>Only 1 Response option is required.<br></h4>
        <label for="allowed1">Option 1</label>
        <input type="text" name="allowed1" id="allowed1" maxlength="12">Max Length = 12
        <label for="allowed2"><br>
          Option 2</label>
        <input type="text" name="allowed2" id="allowed2" maxlength="12">
        <br>
          <label for="allowed3">Option 3</label>
          <input type="text" name="allowed3" id="allowed3" maxlength="12">
          <label for="allowed4"><br>
            Option 4</label>
          <input type="text" name="allowed4" id="allowed4" maxlength="12">
           </div>
        </div>
         <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send Event Message">
         </form>
```

Comment: is this posted to a file on your server ?

Comment: Yes, both are on the same server, and folder

Comment: then i dont understand wahy you would use curl at all

Comment: set form action to "record.php" and then redirect back to form.php afterwards, or intergrate and submit to the same page

Comment: If I change the form to post to record.php, record.php would be loaded in the browser. I have a lot of sleep() in record.php, so I don't want users loading that page if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this is simply not what `curl` is for...

Imagine this:

You have your server - which is where your php code runs, and you have your client, which is who you sent your HTML/CSS/JS to -

The reason this page is buffering forever, is because curl is running, but to no avail, since you are using it improperly.

Curl is used for when you want your server to talk to other servers.

NOW - If you want your form to work properly, don't use CURL, use AJAX --- There are plenty of tutorials, but this one is my favorite, and is how I learned how to use AJAX--

check it out:

http://www.elated.com/articles/slick-ajax-contact-form-jquery-php/

Comment: dont need ajax, just uses php *properly*

Comment: HA, indeed -! But, If you want to submit a form without reloading the page, like the OP asked - you have to use AJAX

Comment: he only does not want to reload the page because his form processing script is sub-optimal fixing that is the preferred strategy